# Update the X-Delete-After time on an existing OpenStack Swift file?

Tags: openstack-swift

I'm using OpenStack Swift as a cache, and using `X-Delete-After` to make sure that old data are deleted.

How can I update or remove the `X-Delete-After` value for an existing file (without re-uploading it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general answer is to `POST` the updated metadata (including the new value for `x-delete-after`) to the object. Remember you need to `POST` the entire contents of the object metadata, not just the part you want updated.

If you've got "fast post" enabled (the `post_as_copy=False` proxy config setting and the default), then the metadata will be updated without copying the file contents on the server-side.

If you don't have fast post enabled, it works the same way, but on the sever side it will end up doing a COPY. This is internal to the cluster, and the object data is not sent to the client.

Comment: Good to know about `post_as_copy`, thanks! Also, is there any way to only update the one piece of metadata? Two round trips isn't ideal.